# navigationBar setTranslucent:NO causes UIButton to disappear

Tags: ios

I found a strange thing. Following is just a simple demo project.

In TestViewController.m:
[image]

In AppDelegate:
[image]

When I set the translucent of the navigationBar to NO, the UIButton in the displayed viewController will not show. Conversely, if I do not set, the button will appear.

Could anyone explain it to me? I believe it is a bug of Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"set the translucent of the navigationBar to NO" will make the height of UIViewController's view reduce 44 point(navigationBar's height) which make your button invisible.

Your button's frame is out of the view's bound. Adjust your uibutton's frame according to the bound of viewController's view.